# intersection of the complement of two disjoint sets is not disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question regarding whether the intersection of the complement of two disjoint set is disjoint or not.

I mean given say $A$ and $B$ with $A$ and $B$ disjoint, i.e. $A \subset X$ and $B \subset X$, and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. It seems that $A^{c} \cap B^{c} \ne \emptyset$, at least when I draw a Venn Diagram, it seems the intersection of the complement is not empty given the condition that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. But somehow I am having some difficulty proving it.

Could someone give me some hint. Because it seems it is not a very difficulty proof. But I kind of get stuck.

Thank you

Comment: Consider $A = \{ n \mid n \in \mathbb N \text { and } n \text { is odd } \}$ and $B = \{ m \mid m \in \mathbb N \text { and } m \text { is even } \}$ $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and also $A^C \cap B^C = \emptyset$.

Comment: The "intersection of the complement" is one set, the set $A^c\cap B^c$. What does it mean for one set to be disjoint??

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you proposed need some alterations.

For example, 
Let:
X=set of real numbers
 $ A = (-\infty , 0 ] \\ $
$ B = (0, \infty )$

So the intersection of the complements are empty.

But the result you proposed is true when A and B are proper subsets of X

Comment: In your counterexample, $A$ and $B$ are proper subsets of $X.$ I think you meant to say "when $A\cup B$ is a proper subset of $X.$"

Comment: Ah yes. Correct. :)

Comment: Hi Charith, so do you mean my conclusion that $A^{c} \cap B^{c} \ne \emptyset$ is correct? so my conclusion is fine based on my guess from the Venn diagram. For example, the Fifth Diagram here: http://www.cs.uni.edu/~campbell/stat/venn.html  , the intersection is clearly non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon you observed doesn't always hold true. Since $B=(B\cap A)\cup(B\cap A^c)$, and we know that $B\cap A=\emptyset$, so $B\cap A^{c}=B$. Therefore $B\subseteq A^{c}$. If $B=A^c$, then $A^{c}\cap B^{c}=A^{c}$\ $B=\emptyset$. If $B\neq A^{c}$ then $A^{c}\cap B^{c}=A^{c}$\ $B\neq\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A^{c} \cap B^{c} = \emptyset$ if and only if its complement is the universe set $X$, by De Morgan law, which is equivalent to $A \cup B = X$.

For example, suppose that $X = \{a,b\}$, and let $A = \varnothing$ and $B = \{b\}$.